# Tikz changes included graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf

I'm including PDF images into my `tikzpicture` environment, and the line widths in the included images are different than in the original PDF (some are thick as they should be, some are thin).

[image: input versus output][1]

A minimal example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.7]
 \node (A) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{example1}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I make `tikzpicture` keep the line widths in example1(.pdf)?

The picture can be downloaded at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25315636/example1.pdf

Comment: Did you make sure that it's not just a display-issue of the PDF-reader? Some behave pretty badly with line-width. Try zooming in or printing the file to verify this. Otherwise, it's pretty hard to figure out without the actual file. I don't get different results with a random .pdf.

Comment: Why `[scale=2.7]`? In your example, the scaling do nothing !

Comment: Yes, I am sure, I'm using the latest PDF reader, plus it is obvious from zooming (and printing). Indeed, the scale does nothing. I guess tikz somehow makes the imported PDF's to use the line widths of tikz instead its own widths... if that makes sense.

Comment: I have now included the image file.

Comment: That's weird! I've added an image to your question. Is this the same you get?

Comment: @HendrikVogt: I get the same result. Strange indeed!

Comment: @Bostjan: How did you generate that PDF image?

Comment: your linewidth in the pdf file is not correct. It can be seen when converting the pdf into an uncompressed one, e.g. with `pdftk`

Comment: Hm... it's saved directly from Adobe Illustrator. I can't imagine Adobe would produce a faulty PDF. Besides I tried to save it with various PDF compatibility versions and the result is always the same.

Comment: @Herbert: you are perfectly right! In this PDF file, first lines use current linewidth (regardless of its value), then other lines use explicitly 1 unit or 0.5 unit. Add `1 w` at the beginning of the stream corrects this error.

Comment: This found for me pdftops -level3 -eps example1.pdf example_1.eps and epstopdf example_1.eps solve the problem

Answer (score 15):

As I already wrote in the comment, the pdf has a wrong linewidth setting. You can repair it by setting explicitly the linewidth:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.7]
 \node (A) at (0,0) {\pdfliteral{ 1 w}\includegraphics{example1}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

yields the output:
[image]

Answer (score 12):

This is not a complete answer but solves the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.7]
 \node (A) at (0,0) [line width=1pt]{\includegraphics{example1.pdf}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \includegraphics{example1}
\end{document}
```

It seems that tikz regards the badly drawn line as its own and applies the default drawing options on it. So its definitely under the tikz regime while it should not be. I could imagine, that your pdf isnt quite valid (some missing boxes maybe, remember pdf creator on Mac isnt perfect at all) or its just a bug.

Comment: Your code proves that the first curves of this PDF file use the current value of linewidth instead of choosing their own value.

Answer (score 5):

Finally it seems that it's difficult to use Adobe Illustrator correctly (you need to fix the line width to avoid to use the current line width). So I propose to draw the picture only with TikZ.

**Remark :** I use a tikzpicture inside a tikzpicture intentionally. If you fix `line width =1pt` in the first tikzpicture, the current `line width` in the second one is `0.4pt`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} 
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\midarrow}{\tikz \draw[-stealth'] (0,0) -- +(.1,0);}
\newcommand{\revmidarrow}{\tikz \draw[-stealth' reversed] (0,0) -- +(.1,0);}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node (A) at (0,0) {%
\begin{tikzpicture}  
 \draw circle[radius=2];
\begin{scope}[line width = 1pt]
    \draw (-120:2) .. controls (-150:0.25) .. (-180:2) node[pos=.8,sloped,scale=2] {\revmidarrow};
    \draw (0:2)    .. controls (-30:0.25) ..  (-60:2)  node[pos=.8,sloped,scale=2] {\midarrow}; 
    \draw (120:2)  .. controls (160:.75) and (180:.5) .. (0:0) 
                   .. controls  (0:.5) and (20:.75)  .. (60:2) 
                      node [pos=.8,sloped,scale=2] {\midarrow}; 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First convert image file

```
pdftoeps -level3 -eps example1.pdf example_1.eps
```

Second reconvert image file

```
epstopdf example_1.eps
```

And try (and compare)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=1]{example_1.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example1.pdf}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example_1.pdf}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Compare result, works for me TexLive 2012/Fedora 17/Acroread 9.5.1
EDIT2: Now works ...

Comment: I get the same results as reported above. Not sure what is different here.

Comment: The answer doesn't work.

Comment: Opss, I se the problem now, your image (from Mac) it`s the problem (i think)