# Protecting the contents of an image from enclosing tikz style specifications

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Consider an image created by the following `fig.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,solid,->] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw[thick,solid,->] (0,0) -- (0,1);
    \draw[thick,solid,->] (0,0) -- (-1,-1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Let's compile it with `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf` to create `fig_latex.pdf` and with `pdflatex` to create `fig_pdflatex.pdf`.

Then include these figures in the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[draw] {regular: \includegraphics{fig_latex.pdf}};
    \draw (0,-3) node[draw, dashed] {dashed latex: \includegraphics{fig_latex.pdf}};
    \draw (0,-6) node[draw, dashed] {dashed pdflatex: \includegraphics{fig_pdflatex.pdf}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

All we're doing is defining TikZ nodes and including the images inside. Now the problem is that for the image compiled with `latex` the enclosing `dashed` specification gets transferred to the image itself, something that doesn't happen with the image compiled with `pdflatex`:

[image: example image: dashed node around tikz image compiled with latex causes the contents to be dashed as well]

Is there a way to protect the contents of the image on the enclosing level, without having to, say, recompile the existing image file using `pdflatex`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can reset the dash pattern with `\pdfliteral{ [] o d}`. But I'm not sure if this is worth it. There can be other graphic parameters which can be wrong. See also [Tikz changes included graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61937/tikz-changes-included-graphics)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,-3) node[draw, dashed] {dashed latex: \includegraphics{fig-latex.pdf} };
    \draw (0,-6) node[draw, dashed] {dashed latex: \pdfliteral{ [] o d}\includegraphics{fig-latex.pdf} };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't manage to find the linked post. I guess I'll follow your suggestion and recompile with pdflatex to make sure that no other property gets changed.